CSS - Multiple :not selector one after the other
I'm trying to select a bunch of elements with :not pseudo-class.
The issue I'm facing is that I'm trying to apply two :not one after the other:
    .nav-menu >li:not(.button):not(:last-of-type){border-bottom:1px solid #000;}

Basically, I want to apply the style to any li but the last one that does not have the .button class.
Or put simply, apply the second :not after the first :not already filtered out elements
Here the related HTML:
 <ul class="nav_menu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li> <!-- This should not be selected -->
        <li class="button"></li> <!-- This one neither -->
    </ul>

I cannot use :nth-last-of-type because the elements can be dynamically changed.
Is it possible without changing the DOM at all ?
Thanks a lot!

No, that is not possible. See duplicate for further explanation.

For your current example above this would work: .nav_menu>li:not(.button):not(:has(+ .button)) - the number of the li before "the last one before the .button one" could be dynamic with this. But if there could be other "normal" li after the button, or any other structurally different situations, it's probably not going to work like you want.

@C3roe - I'm confused. My reading of the duplicate is that it is possible.

.nav_menu>li:nth-last-child(n + 2 of li:not(.button))

Okay, yes, apparently some of the new additions to selectors make this possible now.
